# Set add_image_size() greater than content width in media box

Tags: images, content-width

How can I set a [image size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) bigger then the defined max [content width](https://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Width) in the media box?

The content width is set to:

```php
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) {
    $content_width = 960;
}
```

If I add now a picture with size bigger then the `$content_with`, it get scaled down.

```php
add_image_size( 'post-visual', 2048, 900, true );
```

The picture gets sized but at the moment it appears in the media box only with the dimensions of `960x421`.

Comment: I guess that image scales down by css rules. Check css for that image. There must be max-width: 960px;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Did you use `wp_get_attachment_image_src('$post_id','post-visual');` for getting your desire image sized? If not then try to use this function for getting proper image size.
2. Check CSS  for that image `width` or `max-width` and it has to be `width: 100%;` css property.